# Maximo Anywhere button disable issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working on Anywhere 7.5.2 - work execution app. I tried to disable a button from handlers `eventContext.setDisplay(false)` and I tried with `eventContext.setEditable(false)` but couldn't do the same.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to disable the button in an event handler on the renderevent.

```
renderWorkHandler: function(eventContext){
            // renderWorkHandler
            eventContext.getBaseWidget().domNode.disabled=true
        },
```